# Windows 10/11 widget/system icon for a bluetooth device battery

Tags: windows, bluetooth, taskbar, notification-area, widgets

Normally we often check bluetooth devices battery by this way:
[image: list bluetooth's devices]
But it will be more convenient if we can see it on the system tray like laptop's battery:
[image: laptop's battery icon]
or have a 3rd party app display it like this Lenovo Vantage displays battery:
[image: Vantage]

Are there anyway to quicly check a bluetooth device's battery? Widget is okey too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat working third party app on GitHub called BluetoothLEBatteryMonitor, that displays the battery level as a systray icon:

https://github.com/MUedsa/BluetoothLEBatteryMonitor

In my case it was working to display the battery level of my connected iPhone, but it did no work with my Sony headset. It seems development of the tool has stopped.

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that there exist a shareware which seems to be able to show the battery status of a variety of other devices called "Bluetooth Battery Monitor". You can find it here:

https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/